# How to connect remote database in asp.net using mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string MyConString = "SERVER=http://10.54.3.208:8080/Ager/person;" + "DATABASE=agero;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=root;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        //MySqlConnection command = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();
        string s = "select * from boopathi where STU_ID =@sid and STU_PWD =@pwd";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            {
                Server.Transfer("WebForm1.aspx");
            }
        }      
        //close connection
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In localhost it is working perfectly. Once I set my remote link instead of localhost. It's not connecting anymore. I am getting exception like `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Comment: I guess port 3306 is somewhere blocked in your network path. What is the exception that is raised?

Comment: i was getting "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

Comment: Edit that into your question, that is highly relevant. Did you already check if port 3306 is blocked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:-

```
MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("server=10.54.3.208; database=agero; uid=root; pwd=root");
```

**OR**

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=10.54.3.208;" + "DATABASE=agero;" + "UID=root;" + "Pwd=root;";
```

refer this link for more information [MySQL Connector](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/camilord/connecting-to-remote-mysql-linux-server-using-visual-C-Sharp/

I hope this will solve your problem